# Reversing an ArrayList (Understanding the code)

Tags: java, arraylist

I found an exercise in a book that adds some money into an ArrayList, and then reverses them. I know we can easily use `Collection.reverse()`, which is what my textbook shows, but I found another cool solution online that I am trying to understand but having trouble with.

Heres the code:

```
class Purse {
    private ArrayList<String> coins = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void addCoin(String coinName) {
        coins.add(coinName);
    }

    public void reverse() {
        for(int start = 0, end = coins.size() - 1; start < coins.size() / 2; start++, end--) {
            swap(start,end,coins);
        }
    }

    private void swap(int starting, int ending, List aList) {
        Object temp = aList.set(starting, aList.get(ending));
        aList.set(ending,temp);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Purse: " + coins;
    }

}

public class PurseDemo {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Purse purseObj = new Purse();
        purseObj.addCoin("Quarter");
        purseObj.addCoin("Dime");
        purseObj.addCoin("Penny");
        purseObj.addCoin("Nickel");
        System.out.println(purseObj);
        purseObj.reverse();
        System.out.println(purseObj);
    }
}
```

Here is where my confusion is:

```
Object temp = aList.set(starting,aList.get(ending));
aList.set(ending,temp);
```

First of all, I think I get the idea of this. However, this is my first time seeing the `Object` keyword. What I don't really get is what `temp` actually represents ( I got this code off online, in my book they havent introduced this keyword `Object` yet)

Here are my thoughts on an example iteration

Suppose our arrayList has

```
[Quarter,Dime,Penny,Nickel]
```

According to `Object temp = aList.set(starting,aList.get(ending));`

We take the the first spot in the ArrayList `Quarter` and put the value of `nickel` in there. So we get the ArrayList

```
[Nickel,Dime,Penny,Nickel]
```

Now I'm kind of confused.. When I `system.out.println(temp)`, it tells me the values are `Quarter` and `Dime`. But why? Can someone go through an example iteration with me?

**AFTER READING ANSWER**

```
[Quarter,Dime,Penny,Nickel]
```

`Nickel` replaces `Quarter`, thus temp is `Quarter`. So we add Quarter to the end
I.E we get

```
Quarter,Dime,Penny,Quarter
```

Wait.. But where did our nickel go?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `set()` method returns the object that is being displaced by the new object. The first line

```
Object temp = aList.set(starting,aList.get(ending));
```

is the same as:

```
Object temp = aList.get(starting);
aList.set(starting, aList.get(ending));
```

You could actually do it without the `temp` variable, in one line:

```
aList.set(ending, aList.set(starting, aList.get(ending)));
```

Comment: I think I get what your saying, but now I'm a bit confused as to what happens with nickel, can you see my added edit to my question?

Comment: @cresjoy nickel only gets changed to quarter at the end. Not the beginning.

Comment: How? If temp is quarter when we reach the line aList.set(ending,temp), we set the ending index which is currenrlty Nickel, to temp which is quarter.

Answer (score 0):

The swap method can be translated into its "usual form":

```
Object temp = aList.get(starting);
aList.set(starting, aList.get(ending));
aList.set(ending, temp);
```

All the code you found does is combine the first two lines because `List.set` promises to return the replaced value.

Now let's see your example, where `aList` initially is `[Quarter,Dime,Penny,Nickel]`, and `starting` is `0` and `ending` is `3`.

1. `Object temp = aList.get(starting);`, now `temp` is `Quarter`.
2. `aList.set(starting, aList.get(ending));`, now `aList` is `[Nickel,Dime,Penny,Nickel]`.
3. At last, `aList.set(ending, temp);`, sets the last element of aList to `Quarter`: `[Nickel,Dime,Penny,Quarter]`

Comment: Then on the next iteration we only have [Dime,Penny] correct?

Comment: That's correct, in the next iteration, starting will be 1 and ending will be 2.